# как добавить проверку числа, вводимого пользователем?

Tags: python-3.x

пишу игру "Быки и коровы".
когда пользователь вводит четырёхзначное число,
мне это число нужно проверить
чтобы оно было только из 4х цифр, чтобы не было букв, не начиналось с 0, чтобы все цифры были разными; думаю, вы поняли.
И просить новый ввод до тех пор, пока он не пройдет проверки (сделать цикл)

Comment: Какой код вы уже написали и в чём проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример ввода корректного числа. Функция проверяет параметры числа:

- быть числом
- диапазон [1000-9999]
- все цифры различны

В цикле вводим число, пока не получим корректное.

```
def checkNumber(n):
    if n.isdigit()==True:
        b=int(n)
        digits=set([char for char in n])
        if (b>=1000 and b<=9999) and len(n)==len(digits):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False



number=""
while checkNumber(number)==False:
    number=input("Введите четырехзначное число с разлиными цифрами: ")

number=int(number)
print(number)
```

Comment: Любите все усложнять.

Comment: @Эникейщик не вижу чем ваш код проще.

Answer (score 1):

Более компактный код функции из предыдущего ответа:

```
def checkNumber(number):
    if number.isdigit():
        b = int(number)
        digits = set(number)
        return (1000 < b < 9999) and len(digits) == 4
    else:
        return False
```

И дальше

```
while not checkNumber(number):
```

Comment: Это полностью мой код из ответа. В чем оригинальность?

Comment: Оригинальность никто и не обещал. Он короче и проще.  Меньше спагетти 

Comment: Код пишется понятным  для человека, а не для компьютера. Неявное сравнение это дурной тон. см. Чистый код

Comment: Мой код как раз чистый и не захламлен ненужными `if true==true return true`. Сравнения у меня два и оба они явные. То, что вы приняли за неявное сравнение, сравнением не является.

Comment: Так и пишите свой. Зачем брать мой плохой? Это называется плагиат.

Comment: Я и написал свой. И уточните значение слова "плагиат" в словаре.

Comment: Можно более точно указать диапазон для `b` :) `1234 <= b <= 9876`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов да, пожалуй. Только 1023, 0 ведь в числах можно использовать?

Comment: @Эникейщик Вы правы. Этот случай упустил.